# top view drawings in illustrator

Tags: drawing, adobe, adobe-illustrator

I would like to create a city of top view. For example, something similiar as these images:

http://image.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/73497/73497,1329086967,2/stock-photo-city-top-view-95061103.jpg
http://www.bigcitypix.com/image/big-city-pictures-logo-gearhead-city-buildings-cross-streets-aerial-rooftops-roof-top-high-angle-overhead-view-film-video-shoot-graphic-media-company-brand-image-700x460.gif

I work in adobe Illustrator. Please, how can I do a building of top view? Can I make a building in the perspective view and then rotate to the top view? Or how? Please, if you know about a good tutorial where it is describes, could you send me the link? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first image, I would go to 3d programs like 3ds Max / sketchup for that effect.

For the second image,

You could use:
- draw some squares
- go to "effect" at the top menu, "3D" - "extrude and bevel"

Hope that helps

Comment: Great suggestion on Extrude and Bevel (+1). Worth noting there is a Perspective slider which will help accentuate the effect further

Answer (score 0):

Please check that only first image opens.

Its way too easy to do like this. Just hit "M" in illustrator and start making squares and rectangles.

Cheers!